# How to handle multiple inputs in my codes?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Once I check one checkbox of multiple students, only one student is stored inside my database. I want to get the value of the checkbox of each student added every input of the admin. One more thing is that I want to copy the data of the first name and section inside the table //see comment to "attendance" database. The database of the value inside the table is "student". Thanks in advance.
[image: Here]

> ```
>  <html>
>  <body>
>  <form method = "POST"><strong>
>  Set the date: 
>  </strong>
>  <input type = "date" name = "set_date"></br></br>
>  <table width="800" border="3" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
>  <tr>
>  <th><center>First name</center></th>
>  <th><center>Section</center></th>
>  <th><center>Status</center></th>
>  </tr>
> ```

```
  <?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "avtt123");
  mysql_select_db("arvintarrega",$con);

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student");
  echo "<form action = attendance.php method = POST>";
  while($student=mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {   
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><center>".$student['fname']."</center></td>";  // the 'fname' and the 'section'
  echo "<td><center>".$student['section']."</center></td>"; 
  echo '<td><center><input type = "checkbox" name = "status" value = "Present">Present </input>';
  echo '<input type = "checkbox" name = "status" value = "Absent">Absent </input>';
  }
  echo "</form>";
  echo "</table>";

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'set_date') && filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'status'))
    {
       if(isset($_POST['set_date']) && ($_REQUEST['status']=="Present"))
       {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance(date, status) VALUES('$_POST[set_date]', '$_REQUEST[status]')"; 
        echo '<span style="color:green;"><strong></br>Attendance Complete!<strong></span>';
       }
       else if(isset($_POST['set_date']) && ($_REQUEST['status']=="Absent"))
       {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance(date, status) VALUES('$_POST[set_date]', '$_REQUEST[status]')"; 
        echo '<span style="color:green;"><strong></br>Attendance Complete!<strong></span>';          
       }   
        mysql_query($sql, $con);
    }       
    else 
    echo '<span style="color:red;"><strong></br>All fields are required</strong></span>';
}
  ?>
</br></br>
<input type = "submit" name = "save" value = "Submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change Check-box name to name = "status[]" and then try with foreach

Comment: foreach? can you give me an example :)

Comment: First let me know according to status check box you want to insert multiple record or you want to save all status check box values in a single column?

Comment: only one checkbox value in a single column

Comment: Means you want that if more than one status checkbox is checked then for each one one record should add? Am i right?

Comment: the problem is, I can only get the value of the first person. I can't get the 2nd one.

Comment: Can i edit your code and  mark it. then you check if it works then i will put it as an answer.?